# AndroidStudio :Cannot resolve symbol 'MainActivity'.Using AndroidAnnotations

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

I've decided to use [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) with Android Studio, I wanted to implement it through Gradle.But I got an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'MainActivity_'less...Validate resource references inside Android XML files."

My Version:

> targetSDKversion 22 + compileSdkVersion 22 + buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

But when I configured *Android Studio (1.4.1)* and modified the *AndroidManifest.XML* configuration files,the project was prompted to go wrong.Without my pre-processed class from my `MainActivity`->`MainActivity_`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dimon.org.androidannotation" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity_" >  //here
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I want to know what is the wrong.

Thank you !!!

Here are some code of the *build.gradle(Module and Project).*

**EDIT**

Sharing build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3.2'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dimon.org.androidannotation"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.dimon.org.androidannotation'
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

Root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I think these *build.gradle* configurations are no problem,but just don't konw why will go wrong.

Thank you so much!!

My project had not generated `MainActivity_` file in the `generated/source/apt/debug` directory after I Make Project.Why?

[Table of Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbnSi.png)

I'm using following Versions:

- Android Studio 1.4.1
- Gradle version 1.3.0
- android-apt 1.4
- AndroidAnnotations Version 3.3.2

> If there should be a solution to this problem please tell me! Thanks!!
>
> ADD:
>
> I finally succeeded in generating a MainActivity_ file. Because my original order precompiled error cause can not be generated .I actually made ​​a simple mistake, really is brain cramp. Thanks to every one who answered , feeling you help me eliminate confusion, thank you ! !

Comment: What is your class name `MainActivity_` or `MainActivity` ?

Comment: please provide package name of MainActivity_ and be sure you extent Activity to this class

Comment: Did you make the project first? The `MainActivity_` file is generated, so it is not present before the first successful build.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya The MainActivity_ file is actutally generated.So this class name is MainActivity.Bucause Android Studio version upgrade, lead to some configuration generated options disappeared.Compile directly can't generate `MainActivity_` inteligentlu.

Comment: @DedaniyaHiren `MainActivity_` file is actutally generated.I mean why haven't I generate the file.

Comment: Remove `resourcePackageName` from apt plugin config.

Comment: @bigdestroyer I tried your method, without success, is still an error.

Comment: @WonderCsabo I know `MainActivity_` file is generated, but my project had not generated `MainActivity_` file in the `generated/source/apt/debug` directory after I Make Project.Why?

Comment: Can you share the project so we can check it?

Comment: @WonderCsabo Oh ! I finally succeeded in generating a MainActivity_ file. Because my original order precompiled error cause can not be generated .Really appreciate your help . I can continue to learn AndroidAnnotations this framework.Thanks!!!

Comment: you could answer your comment which you add after question as a new answer so we can be clear that you have find the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this .

```
activity android:name="com.dimon.org.androidannotation.MainActivity_"
```

**Better Approach**

1. **Change your class name (Refactor)** and set `MainActivity`

Then

- Rebuilding the project
- Cleaning the project
- Syncing with Gradle Files
- Closing the Project, closing AS and relaunching / reopening
- File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: My project had not generated `MainActivity_` file in the `generated -> source -> apt -> debug` after I Make Project.Why?Thanks.

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches / Restart helped! Thank you.